# Examine how the variables are allocated in the heap memory (for debugging runtime errors)

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, heap-memory

For example, the following code causes `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`

```cpp
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> foo(10, 0);
  std::vector<int> bar(10, 1);
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    foo[i] = 42;
  }
  bar.clear(); // causes munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
}
```

In this simple example, I can easily guess that `bar` is allocated after `foo` in the heap memory, so can guess some operation on `foo` "break" the memory of `bar`. so fixing the bug is fairly easy.

However in a real application, the situation could be much more complex and we can't easily guess the heap memory allocation.

So my question is:

1. Is there way to show how variables are allocated in the heap?
2. Is it possible to monitor which function break certain memory accidentally?

Comment: Use Address Sanitizer.  You have discovered Undefined Behaviour - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: 2. [valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/valgrind/info)

Comment: _"I can easily guess that `bar` is allocated after `foo` in the heap memory"_ that is not a reliable guess to make.  Writing to `foo[10]` is simply undefined behavior, no matter what address `bar` resides at.

Comment: @DrewDormann is right. The compiler doesn't have to generate any code for undefined behavior, so foo[10] might not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way to show how variables are allocated in the heap?

Yes: you can examine locations that `vector` will use in a debugger. For example (using your program) and GDB:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1185: file t.cc, line 3.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdbb8) at t.cc:3
3         std::vector<int> foo(10, 0);
(gdb) n
4         std::vector<int> bar(10, 1);
(gdb) p/r foo
$1 = {<std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl_data> = {_M_start = 0x55555556aeb0, _M_finish = 0x55555556aed8, _M_end_of_storage = 0x55555556aed8}, <No data fields>}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) n
5         for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
(gdb) p/r bar
$2 = {<std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl_data> = {_M_start = 0x55555556aee0, _M_finish = 0x55555556af08, _M_end_of_storage = 0x55555556af08}, <No data fields>}}, <No data fields>}
```

Here you can see that `foo` will use locations `0x55555556aeb0` through `0x55555556aed8`, and `bar` will use `0x55555556aee0` through `0x55555556af08`.

Note however that these locations may change from run to run, especially in multi-threaded programs, making this technique *very* difficult to use.

If your problem can be found by the Address Sanitizer, that would be significantly faster and more reliable approach.

> Is it possible to monitor which function break certain memory accidentally?

Yes: that's what watchpoints are for. For example, we don't expect the location pointed to by `foo._M_impl._M_end_of_storage` to be changed, so we can set a watchpoint on it:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1185: file t.cc, line 3.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdbb8) at t.cc:3
3         std::vector<int> foo(10, 0);
(gdb) n
4         std::vector<int> bar(10, 1);
(gdb) n
5         for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

(gdb) watch *(int*)0x55555556aed8
Hardware watchpoint 2: *(int*)0x55555556aed8

(gdb) c
Continuing.

Hardware watchpoint 2: *(int*)0x55555556aed8

Old value = 49
New value = 42
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdbb8) at t.cc:5
5         for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

(gdb) p i
$1 = 10     <-- voila, found the place where overflow happened.
```